# Why is AWS Glue taking time to start the execution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, etl, aws-glue

[image]

Once execution started it's completing in just few seconds but pending execution itself is taking 10 to 15 minutes, I agree that it's setting up the env for running the job, but In my case, I need to run this job(transforming JSON) for every 15 min, will this workout or any option is there? Am I missing any configuration?

Comment: It is not the configuration problem but the AWS Queue is the matter I think.

Comment: @Lamanus Thanks for the response, Is Glue is not the right option for this kind of jobs with time constraint? or is there any way we can improve this?

Comment: The job takes just few second, then I'd recommend using the lambda, cuz even if you use for a second, it will charge the minimum 10 mins. Or if you don't matter about the precise time scheduling, then submit the job with the scheduling that will be working but delayed.

Comment: Thanks @Lamanus for the quick response

Comment: @Gobi Can you confirm if you are reading from /writing to a DB with your Glue job? If not the job should not take much time to complete it execution and especially when you schedule this to run every 15 minutes